# How to catch all old-style class exceptions in python?

Tags: python, exception, python-2.x

In a code where there are different old-style classes like this one:

```
class customException: pass
```

and exceptions are raised this way:

```
raise customException()
```

Is there a type to catch all those old-style class exceptions? like this:

```
try:
    ...
except EXCEPTION_TYPE as e:
    #do something with e
```

Or at least is there a way to catch everything (old- and new-style) and get the exception object in a variable?

```
try:
    ...
except:
    #this catches everything but there is no exception variable
```

Comment: Related: http://python3porting.com/differences.html#except

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only solution I can think of is using `sys.exc_info`

```
import sys
try:
    raise customException()
except:
    e = sys.exc_info()[1]
    # handle exception "e" here...
```